# Sharepoint 2007 - Get pages if current site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

I'm trying to make a webpart which shows all pages of current site.

To represent it I need just Title, Description and URL of page.

I have figured out that every page is in "Pages" list, but there are no such data as Title etc.

Do you have any solution for getting Pages data in SP 2007?

Answer (score 0):

To get the pages data, you just query the pages library (I assume you have a field named Description in the library).

```
var query = new SPQuery();
var list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Pages"];
var items = list.GetItems(query);
foreach (var item in items)
{
    string title = item["Title"] as string;
    string url = item.Url;
    string description = item["Description"] as string;
}
```

Comment: var items = list.GetItems(items); <- I think that there's mistake in this line

Comment: Thanks for that, one more question. After getting results of that, my Url is bad, i mean it looks like http://xxxx/sites/xxx/Pages/Pages/myTestPage.aspx   You can see that Pages are mentioned twice in a link, any idea where is the problem?